# Spring Rest API Url Mapping Issue

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-restcontroller, spring-rest

I am simulating the issue as described below:

There are two functions convert and create. Below is the sample code of the same.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/products", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public class ProductResourceImpl implements ProductResource {

    private final SomeFactory someFactory;

    public ProductResourceImpl(final SomeFactory someFactory) {
        this.someFactory = someFactory;
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping(value = "/model/convert")
    public Product convert(@RequestBody ProductConversionRequest productConversionRequest) {
        // Do processing
    }

    @Override
    @PostMapping(value = "/model")
    public Product create(@RequestBody ProductCreateRequest productCreateRequest) {
        // Do processing
    }
```

I also tried with the different orders of the functions as well but facing the same issue.
And not getting why I am facing this issue.

**EDIT:** It is working for convert `@PostMapping(value = "/model/convert")` but not working for crate `@PostMapping(value = "/model")` and when i updated create endpoint with `@PostMapping(value = "/model/anything")` it started working. 
I am not getting why it shows error for post url `/products/model`.

Below are the logs of the same. Really thankful to your suggestions and help in advance.

```
"Request method 'POST' not supported"
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:200) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:419) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:365) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:65) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
```

Comment: did u use spring-security?

Comment: Can you add the request to the post?

Comment: @Golam Mazib sajib, i am not using spring-security (no need here) it is just related to mapping only

Comment: @Amir M, i can paas any junk data as well, if it is not parsable it will give me invalid json error but it will not fail to mapping the handler, so here issue is not with request data.